# Wrong length of a character array component after allocation

Tags: fortran, character

I would like to create a derived type containing allocatable character array components. However, when I try to allocate memory in subroutines, nothing happens. It may be more clear with the code example below:

```
program test

  type t1
     character(len=:), allocatable :: c(:)
  end type t1

  type(t1) :: t

  call test_string1()
  call test_string2(t)

contains

  subroutine test_string1()
    character(len=:), allocatable :: c(:)

    allocate( character(10) :: c(1) )
    write(*, *) 'Size in string1: ', len(c)
  end subroutine test_string1


  subroutine test_string2(this)
    class(t1) :: this

    allocate( character(10) :: this%c(1) )
    write(*, *) 'Size in string2: ', len(this%c)
  end subroutine test_string2


end program test
```

I expect that the output of such a code would be:

```
 Size in string1:           10
 Size in string2:           10
```

However, what I actually get is the following:

```
 Size in string1:           10
 Size in string2:            0
```

Therefore, the second subroutine allocates nothing for the `t1%c`... What am I doing wrong here ?
I have compiled the code with:

```
gfortran -c test.f08
gfortran -o test test.o
```

and the version of `gfortran` is the following:

```
$ gfortran -v
...
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

Comment: The only thing you are doing wrong is using a compiler with a bug!  Appears to be fixed in gfortran 9.

Comment: Yup, I've just tried and that was it... Thanks for the tip !

Comment: This code will be used to generate a command executed by 'execute_command_line', so I think the term "string" would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug (or lack of support) in the version of the compiler you are using.  In gfortran versions 7 and 8 I see the same problem, but as noted, gfortran 9 gives the expected answer.  "Use a different compiler/version" is an answer to your question.

What is sometimes helpful in cases like this is the additional question: "what can I do to work around this bug without changing compiler?"

The example of the question is fairly simple leading to not many options.  Intrinsic assignment of a constructed array, or sourced allocation don't help.

Is there something interesting that does?  Why, yes!  Parameterized derived types.

It appears that gfortran 8 experiences the problem of the question but does support derived type parameterization (gfortran 7 doesn't support this Fortran 2003 feature).  This could be a good work around, or even a good alternative approach to the real problem:

```
program test

  type t1(length, size)
     integer, len :: length, size
     character(len=length) :: c(size)
  end type t1

  class(t1(:,:)), allocatable :: t

  call test_string1()
  call test_string2(t)

contains

  subroutine test_string1()
    character(len=:), allocatable :: c(:)

    allocate( character(10) :: c(1) )
    write(*, *) 'Size in string1: ', len(c)
  end subroutine test_string1


  subroutine test_string2(this)
    class(t1(:,:)), allocatable :: this

    allocate( t1(10,1) :: this )
    write(*, *) 'Size in string2: ', len(this%c)
  end subroutine test_string2


end program test
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't know about derived type parametrization ! In the project I am working on I am free concerning the choice of compilers, but this is something to know when distributing the program.