# Fortran character array in derived data type

Tags: arrays, fortran, character, derived-types

I am experiencing a behavior in Fortran I wasn't expecting in character arrays contained in derived types.

The following code describes the strange behaviour:

```
module mod_test_bug

  type data
    character(:), dimension(:), allocatable :: array
  end type data

end module mod_test_bug

program test_bug

  use mod_test_bug

  implicit none

  type(data) :: mydata
  character(:), dimension(:), allocatable :: testdata

  allocate(character(len=5) :: testdata(2))
  allocate(character(len=5) :: mydata%array(2))

  testdata(1) = "test1"

  write(6,*) 'testdata(1) = ', testdata(1)
  write(6,*) 'testdata(2) = ', testdata(2)
  
  testdata(2) = "test2"

  write(6,*) 'testdata(1) = ', testdata(1)
  write(6,*) 'testdata(2) = ', testdata(2)

  mydata%array(1) = "test1"

  write(6,*) 'mydata%array(1) = ', mydata%array(1)
  write(6,*) 'mydata%array(2) = ', mydata%array(2)

  mydata%array(2) = "test2"

  write(6,*) 'mydata%array(1) = ', mydata%array(1)
  write(6,*) 'mydata%array(2) = ', mydata%array(2)

end program test_bug
```

This is the output:

```
testdata(1) = test1
testdata(2) = 
testdata(1) = test1
testdata(2) = test2
mydata%array(1) = test1
mydata%array(2) = test1
mydata%array(1) = test2
mydata%array(2) = test2
```

As you can see, the behavior for the local variable testdata is what I was expecting. However, when looking at the mydata%array character array in the derived type, it seems that any assignment I try to do to to one of its dimensions gets carried to the remaining dimensions (when I declare mydata%array(1) = "test1", it gets carried to the mydata%array(2) as well).

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this with gfortran? Looks like a compiler bug to me - if rather than having the length as allocatable you set it to 5 it works as expected with gfortran versions 6, 7 and 8

Comment: Your program isn't valid Fortran (you reference elements `tesdata(2)` `mydata%array(2)` before you define them). Before we look at whether there is a problem with the final assignment can you fix these errors?

Comment: Yes, this is with gfortran gcc version 8.4.0. And to answer your comment @francescalus, I only added those for illustrative purposes, I had them removed beforehand. The problem persists.

Comment: @IanBush I thought character arrays were of common usage in Fortran, that's why a compiler bug wasn't my first thought.

Comment: Older releases of gfortran certainly [are buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60166578/3157076) when it comes to deferred length character components. The problem here (with corrected code) works as expected with gfortran 10.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your input. I will fix their size for now, since I want to maintain compatibility with the gfortran version I am currently using.

Comment: I wrote an answer before I saw that I said exactly the same thing in response to the question I linked to before. That means that the bug/workaround are sufficiently close to being the same to be seen as duplicates. The look of the problem here is different, and you can have the additional workaround as commented on having a fixed length component, but do consider the parameterized type I mention over there.

Comment: Ok, thanks @francescalus, I will have a look!